# Why can I only select certain colors in the color wheel selector in 2.8?

Tags: color

So ever since I've moved to Blender 2.8 I've noticed my base color wheel is restricted to certain portions of the spectrum. For instance, if I drag my mouse around the border of the entire color wheel, the cursor will only be able to reach a few areas on the edge and otherwise be forced inwards. I've attached an image of where my cursor can reach.

[image]

In addition to this, whenever I select (say) a bright pink (BC5AB9) and attempt to darken the colour via the shade slider on the right, it will revert my color selection back to the center and make my material white/black again.

EDIT: by request, here are my colour management settings

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. My build is from today and I'm on a Mac

Comment: Take a screenshot of color managment tab in render settings